# Get-NetAdapter ghost interfaces

Tags: windows-10, powershell

When I run Get-NetAdapter it shows me a bunch of adapters which are not seen anywhere else in the system, something like:

```
Mobile network 11     HP hs3210 HSPA+ Mobile Broadband Device      37 Not Present                             0 bps
Mobile network 13     HP hs3210 HSPA+ Mobile Broadband Device      35 Not Present                             0 bps
Mobile network 5      HP hs3210 HSPA+ Mobile Broadband Device      34 Not Present                             0 bps
```

About fifteen in total
The question is why do they exist, and how to get rid of them ?

Comment: How do you connect  to your mobile?

Comment: @RohitGupta I do not use it at all

Comment: Event logs may show it, google *"where to find creation of network interfaces for windows in the event viewer logs"* for a potential starting point for other things to investigate. Another idea if you do not use them and they are not important to your network usage on this machine would be to run PowerShell commands to remove/delete those, see if it works, and see if they come back. Still find a log to show more verbose detail. Disable wifi if you are network hard wired, disable bluetooth if you do not use it, etc.

Comment: Look here too, this may be relevant: https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04778344 and maybe disable the equivalent in your case via Device Manager will suffice to remove and ensure it does not come back.